# cycle through a lazy sequence of maps and change one of the values in one of the maps

Tags: clojure

I have a lazy sequence of some number of maps.
I want to cycle through each map and do:
if (= :b "this one") then change :c to 99.

```
({:a 1
  :b "this one"
  :c 100}
 {:a "A"
  :c "Q"
  :z "Z"})
```

Comment: something like this would do: `(mapv #(cond-> % (= "this one" (:b %)) (update :c dec)) data)` => `[{:a 1, :b "this one", :c 99} {:a "A", :c "Q", :z "Z"}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(map #(if (= (:b %) "this one") (assoc % :c 99) %) data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```clj
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (let [data   [{:a 1
                 :b "this one"
                 :c 100}
                {:a "A"
                 :c "Q"
                 :z "Z"}]
        result (vec (for [curr-map data]
                      (if (= "this one" (:b curr-map))
                        (assoc curr-map :c 99)
                        curr-map)))]
    (is= result
      [{:a 1, :b "this one", :c 99}
       {:a "A", :c "Q", :z "Z"}])))
```

based on [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).  Please see the [list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), esp. the Clojure CheatSheet and books like *Getting Clojure*

Comment: I would love that, but how can I turn ({:a 1...) into a vector instead?

Comment: Just use `(vec <some collection>)`, or write it as a literal. Also, the answer will still work with your original list of maps.